# Does MySql analyze / optimize queries before executing them?

Tags: mysql, sql

If you'd write a query like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `views` > 200 OR `views` > 100
```

Would MySql analyze that query and realize that it's actually equivalent to this?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `views` > 100
```

In other words, would MySql optimize the query such that it skips any unnecessary `WHERE` checks?

I'm asking because I'm working on a piece of code that, for now, generates queries with redundant `WHERE` clauses. I'm wondering if I should optimize those queries *before* I send them to MySql, or if that's unnecessary, because MySql would do it anyway.

Comment: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html   It is all in the docs

Comment: For `select` statements , see : (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statement-optimization.html)

Comment: Yes, and much more: [10 Cool SQL Optimisations That do not Depend on the Cost Model](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. MySQL does optimize queries before running them. In fact, what runs has no obvious relationship to the SQL statement itself -- it is a *directed acyclic graph*.

In the process, MySQL determines what indexes to use for the query, what join algorithms, sorts lists of constants in `in` lists, and much more.

The optimizer also does some simplifications of the query. I'm not sure if those simplifications extend to inequalities. However, there is little overhead in making the comparison twice.

Comment: When you say "however, there is little overhead in making the comparison twice", I wonder if that still holds true if a query becomes very long with lots of nested AND and OR statements, many of which may be redundant.

Oh well, I'll just leave it like this for now and reinvestigate if I ever get performance issues in the future.

Comment: @Evert . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  There are clearly comparisons that are more expensive, but inequality on numbers is not particularly expensive, especially compared to reading t he data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` Shows how the query was rewritten -- but it still has the OR.

The "Optimizer trace" says the same thing.  However, when it gets into discussing the "cost", it gets smart and merges the two comparisons.  (This is the case at least as far back as 5.6.)

In many cases, `OR` should be avoided like covid.